# Multiple NullPointerExceptions with ResourceBundleEditor in Eclipse Neon

Tags: spring-tool-suite, resourcebundle, eclipse-neon

Fresh Spring Tool Suite 3.8.2 (Eclipse Neon 4.6.1) with ResourceBundleEditor installed.

When opening `.properties` files, multiple `NullPointerException`s pop up.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.core.model.BreakpointAdapterFactory.getAdapter(BreakpointAdapterFactory.java:25)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.adapter.AdapterFactoryProxy.getAdapter(AdapterFactoryProxy.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:294)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.getAdapter(WorkbenchPart.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.getAdapter(AbstractTextEditor.java:6185)
>       at com.essiembre.eclipse.rbe.ui.editor.i18n.I18nPageEditor.getAdapter(I18nPageEditor.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters.adapt(Adapters.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters.adapt(Adapters.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.getAdapter(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1199)
>       at com.essiembre.eclipse.rbe.ui.editor.ResourceBundleEditor.getAdapter(ResourceBundleEditor.java:208)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager$ToggleBreakpointsTargetAdapterFactory.canGetToggleBreakpointsTarget(ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.java:318)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager$ToggleBreakpointsTargetAdapterFactory.isEnabled(ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.java:361)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.getEnabledFactories(ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.java:502)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.getPreferredToggleBreakpointsTargetID(ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.java:542)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.getToggleBreakpointsTarget(ToggleBreakpointsTargetManager.java:549)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.breakpoints.RetargetBreakpointAction.getAdapter(RetargetBreakpointAction.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.RetargetAction.partActivated(RetargetAction.java:169)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$1.run(PartService.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partActivated(PartService.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$WWinPartService.partActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:3002)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$14.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4977)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4974)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$19(WorkbenchPage.java:4962)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:210)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:250)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:247)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:757)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:63)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1542)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1505)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.sendFocusEvent(Control.java:2940)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmSetFocus(Widget.java:2437)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_SETFOCUS(Control.java:5438)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_SETFOCUS(Tree.java:7195)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4861)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:6074)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2446)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1552)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_LBUTTONDOWN(Tree.java:6759)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4827)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:6074)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5102)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3814)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

How do I get rid of the exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the JSDT Chromium debugger, more specifically, remove files `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.*` from Eclipse plugins directory.